Testcontainers.net Container to SQL Server container communication
I have two containers being managed by Testcontainers.net.
_dockerImage = new ImageFromDockerfileBuilder()
    .WithDockerfileDirectory(CommonDirectoryPath.GetSolutionDirectory(), String.Empty)
    .WithDockerfile("Dockerfile")
    .WithBuildArgument(
        "RESOURCE_REAPER_SESSION_ID",
        ResourceReaper.DefaultSessionId.ToString("D"))
    .Build();

_dbContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
    .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
    .WithPassword("Redacted")
    .WithNetwork(_network)
    .Build();

I have a network configured to join these two containers together:
private readonly INetwork _network = new NetworkBuilder()
    .WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"))
    .Build();

When configuring the _dockerImage I'm passing in environment variables including the database connection string.
ContainerInstance = new ContainerBuilder()
    .WithImage(_dockerImage)
    .WithEnvironment("Database", _dbContainer.GetConnectionString())

When triggering the _dockerImage I'm receiving the following errors:

"@t": "2024-11-12T10:10:24.3595068Z",
"@mt": "An error occurred using the connection to database '{database}' on server '{server}'.",
"@l": "Error",
"@tr": "f0475e9c5a004a4f9ad2dd971f93a5ca",
"@sp": "d7377404f6cef3c5",
"database": "master",
"server": "127.0.0.1,56779",

I suspect it's to do with the connection string being for the host talking into the container rather than a container talking to another container, but I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this.

How to set up a container-to-container communication is described in here. Basically, you connect using the network alias and container port (not via the Docker host and random assigned host port).

Thanks. I had already done this. The issue seems to be that _dbContainer.GetConnectionString() returns a connection string for the host, not for a container. Instead I had to manually construct the connection string. Entity framework is now connecting to something, but doesn't seem to be picking up the data I'm inserting into the table.

This behavior is intentional. The GetConnectionString() method does not return a connection string for container-to-container communication. You will need to construct the connection string yourself. Here is an example of a similar implementation that might be helpful.

Thanks. The important part that was catching me out, was using the network alias as the server name, instead of the container name. All working now. Thanks.
